# How to find java path and make a shortcut with jar files?

Tags: java, shortcuts, minecraft, openjdk

I'm very new to Ubuntu, installed 12.04 for the first time a few days ago.

So I basiclly got a game (feedthebeast, mod for minecraft). Now the jar file which I downloaded works just fine, but I find it clunky to go find it everytime I want to play, so I want a shortcut.

Someone on Youtube made this as a `.sh` file which I can then later make a `.desktop` in my applications to make the shortcut, pretty complicated tbh but the path in this file is obv his path.

```
BINDIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -fn "$0")")"
cd "$BINDIR"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-ora­cle/jre/lib/amd64"
java -Xms1G -Xmx4G -jar ~/.ftblauncher/FTB_Launcher.jar
```

But how do I find MY java path, the correct one for this to work. I tried multiple ways, but for some reason I don't got the folders, where people are suposed to have java - when I run `whereis java` this is what I get:

```
/usr/bin/java /usr/bin/x11/java/ /usr/share/java/ /usr/share/man/man1/java1.gz
```

Neither looks like the one he used above.

I installed java following this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_494531&feature=iv&src_vid=I_NDc01lMB4&v=iKzUzo21vDk

Essentially I jsut want a shortcut for my .jar file so I can easily access my game on the unity dock

If you guys can help me, or come up with an easier way to make this shortcut for my .jar file I would be so happy!

Answer (score 1):

just make a launcher like this:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

in the "command" box put in

```
java -Xms1G -Xmx4G -jar /full/path/to/FTB_Launcher.jar
```

that should leave you with a launcher on your desktop.
copy that to `~/.local/share/applications` to get it on your launcher.

---

By " jar file which I downloaded works just fine" I assume you are launching it by double-clicking /right-click->open-ing the file? if that works fine try these steps:

1) press `ctrl+alt+t` ; this will open a terminal

2)enter / paste this : `cd .ftblauncher` ; the terminal prompt will end with `~/.ftblauncher$`

3)enter `java -Xms1G -Xmx4G -jar FTB_Launcher.jar` ; If this launches FTB, then we can go to the next step: (do you have 4G of ram? -Xmx4G means use a max of 4GB)

4)This suggests that FTB needs to know where it's files are: it needs its "current directory" set. we can do this by making a small launcher script: (it's essentially the same as the one you showed, just waay simpler) Save the following code in a some file, say `ftb.sh`. Set it to be executable (right-click->properties->permissions->allow executing.)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/.ftblauncher
java -Xms1G -Xmx4G -jar FTB_Launcher.jar
```

5)make the launcher as before, only this time let the command be `/full/path/to/ftb.sh` ; make the file executable by right-click->properties->permissions->allow executing.

---

getting hands really dirty:
save this as `ftb.desktop`. the icon line is optional if you can get your hands on a small icon .png file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=/path/to/icon.png
Name[en_US]=Feed the beast
Exec=/full/path/to/ftb.sh
Name=Feed the beast
Icon=/path/to/icon.png
```

mark the file as executable
you can just drag it onto the launcher..
(mark as solved when u done :) good luck )

Comment: Sorry as stated I'm very new to linux

and I don't understand how to make the launcher that way, can ou specify which programs I need to open and where I need to put this info etc.

Comment: Ok I figured out how to make the launcher icon, but for some reason it ain't working
java -Xms1G -Xmx4G -jar /home/Leonpn/.ftblauncher/FTB_Launcher.jar 
Thats my path, it looks correct to me, so don't know what is wrong

Comment: hmm... is the launcher (made by entering the command in the terminal) set to be executable? anyway, I've given another method. Sorry If i'm a bit verbose.. tried to explain my steps so you can experiment on your own and become a linux geek too :P

Comment: Pew!!
Did a lot of messing around with this but I got it working, much love - your guide was very helpfull, I basicly just had to edit the ram to 2GB since thats what I got and in command: /home/[username]/.ftblauncher/FTB.sh 
So simple when you figure it hehe - cheers again.

Comment: Ran into another problem! - I got the launcher on the desktop and works perfectly! but. I can't get it on my unity launcher. when I go to dash it's there and I can run the program from there. It doesn't have text beneath it like the rest of my applications though and when I try to drag it out onto my launcher it just disappears :/

What I would like is to get it working on the launcher and then delete the original on the desktop since I don't need 2 shortcuts, but when I deleted it or put it into the .local/share/applications it wouldn't work - so I had to copy it there in order for it to work

Comment: did you give it a name while creating the launcher? (in the dialogbox)